# Elasticsearch: store log for a week

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

I want to use Elasticsearch to store a log. However, due to the size of log, I plan to only store logs up to a week old. How to do this? Can I set a expire time when I insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a TTL to the "document" like it described here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html